# discord.py new invite link

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm trying to make it so when ever you do the invite command it will make a brand new invite to the server with unlimited uses and never expires, this is the current code i've made but doesn't work and i'm struggling to work-out why, I've looked online and found nothing I hope you guys can all help :)

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def invite(ctx):
        invitelinknew = await bot.create_invite(destination = ctx.message.channel, xkcd = True, max_uses = 100)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Discord Invite Link", description=invitelinknew, color=0xf41af4)
        embed.set_footer(text="Discord server invited link.")
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: The entire code, I'm guestting this part

Comment: invitelinknew = await bot.create_invite(destination = ctx.message.channel, xkcd = True, max_uses = 100)

Comment: Are you getting any output in the terminal from which you are running your bot?

Comment: No I am not. aaaa

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want the bot to send the invite link directly to the chat because of the line: `await bot.say(embed=embed)`.

First of all, I'm not sure setting the variable to `embed` is a good idea because this name might already be in use (not 100% sure though).

I believe that the issue with your code is the last line where the bot sends the message. Since there is no traceback, this is hard to tell for sure but I think replacing it with: `await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=embed)` should fix your problem.

I would change the code to something like this instead:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def invite(ctx):
        invitelinknew = await bot.create_invite(destination = ctx.message.channel, xkcd = True, max_uses = 100)
        embedMsg=discord.Embed(color=0xf41af4)
        embedMsg.add_field(name="Discord Invite Link", value=invitelinknew)
        embedMsg.set_footer(text="Discord server invited link.")
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=embedMsg)
```

Feel free to comment if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @BenitzOriginal Honestly, I have no clue. This was two years ago and I haven't worked on Discord bots since. I'll try to find out :P

Comment: @BenitzOriginal I can't find anything in the docs so it must have just been a copy+paste from somewhere else. Sorry :/

Comment: :( how do I make it so it doesn't expire?

Comment: @BenitzOriginal Unfortunately, I pretty much forgot everything about Discord bot development so I can only refer you to the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_invite#discord.TextChannel.create_invite